# Uniform continuity and inverse images

Tags: continuity

Given: $f: X → Y, x\in X$, and $f$ is continuous at $x$, $f$ is continuous on $X$.

Prove that $f$ is continuous on $X$ if and only if for each open subset $V$ of $Y$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $X$.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with inverse functions (so I removed the tags). Here $f^{-1}(V)$ denotes the set $\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in V\}$ and $f^{-1}$ is not a notation for inverse function of $f$.

Comment: @drhab okay thank you